# Android: Adding external library to project not working

Tags: java, android, jsoup, libs

I am trying to add Jsoup library to my project, but I am getting an error in the program saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'Jsoup'". Below is what I have done, but not working.

1)From the Jsoup website, I downloaded the core library jsoup-1.10.2.jar 
2)Dragged and dropped the .jar file under libs folder in my project 
3)Under build.gradle in dependencies, I added the following line

```
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.10.2.jar')
```

4)In MainActivity.java file, I tried to add the following line

```
String url = "http://example.com";
try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    //more code here
}
```

Then, Jsoup turns red and says "Cannot resolve symbol 'Jsoup'".
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I visited many websites and watched a few tutorial videos and I followed them. But I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you add this line into your module's `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Yes I did, yet I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `build.gradle` you should have the following:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    ...
}
```

You can see the instructions [here](https://jsoup.org/download), in Gradle section.