# Cannot use jsoup in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I tried installing jsoup using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31lJ7QvEyIQ)

Then, a bunch of issues appeared, one after the other:

[first thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146916/android-adding-external-library-to-project-not-working/42147154#42147154)

[happened twice, for other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

[fixed by ending java in task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914499/error-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file)

[fixed by clicking run after clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352591/android-error-converting-byte-to-dex)

After fixing all that, I tried running my test app (this is my MainActivity)

```
package babis.querytest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("qt","before");
    try {
        Log.i("qt","before1");
        Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
        Log.i("qt","after0");
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    Log.i("qt","after");
}
}
```

My Logcat is this

> 01-18 20:05:38.758 17236-17236/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   01-18 20:05:39.040 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.323 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.398 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.460 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.530 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.610 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.688 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.760 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.825 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.898 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.962 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/babis.querytest-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@babis.querytest-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   01-18 20:05:39.964 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/babis.querytest-1/lib/arm64
>   01-18 20:05:39.975 17236-17236/babis.querytest I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   01-18 20:05:40.181 17236-17236/babis.querytest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   01-18 20:05:40.516 17236-17236/babis.querytest I/qt: before
>   01-18 20:05:40.516 17236-17236/babis.querytest I/qt: before1
>   01-18 20:05:40.897 17236-17236/babis.querytest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17236 SIG: 9

and my build.gradle is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "babis.querytest"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/README.md'
    exclude 'META-INF/CHANGES'
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation project(':jsoup-1.11.2')
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'

}
```

my Manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="babis.querytest">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

the app crashes on the Document line. what is the issue?(wifi is working)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: on my MainActivity, the app crashes on the line creating a Document(edited my post to make it clearer)

Comment: Please show the stack trace. The logcat you posted does not seem to have anything to do with your app or the current problem.

Comment: it didn't show any errors or stacktraces, it simply crashed

Comment: I apologize, the video didn't explain I had to use an AsyncTask, sorry for wasting your time (can someone close this question please?)

Comment: That is a common error when first learning network programming on Android. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to run it in an async task not on the main thread

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, YourDataObject>() {
            @Override
            protected YourDataObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
                // parse the document here and return what ever data you want
                return myFunData;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(YourDataObject data) {
                //update UI based on results of parsing html
            }
        }.execute((Void) null);
```